# How can I select the items belonging to a person during a given period when the current owned item's return date is always '2099-12-31'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working with a software that use a database with a given model. I can't change the model.

It's a table with item owned by a person during a specified period.

Here is how it works :

| Owner | Item | Date_from | Date_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Louis | Ring | 2000-01-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| Louis | Hat | 2021-04-01 | 2021-04-30 |
| Louis | Jeans | 2021-05-01 | 2099-12-31 |

In this software when I give a first item to an owner, it wrotes the `date_from` to `2020-01-01` by default and the `date_to` to `2099-12-31`.

So basically when `Date_To` value is `2099-12-31` it means that this item is the one that is currently owned by `Louis`.

So If I have a value like this :

| Owner | Item | Date_from | Date_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Game | 2000-01-01 | 2099-12-31 |

It mean that the item `Game` is the first item owned by `John` (because of the `2000-01-01`) and it is still owned by him (because of the `2099-12-31`).

Louis can **only own one item for a period**. He has to bring the item back to get an new one. When he does this, the software change the current `Date_to` with the return date. And the new item has a `Date_From` that is one day after the return date and a `Date_To` to `2099-12-31`.

Like this (the return date is `2021-03-31`) :

| Owner | Item | Date_from | Date_To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Game | 2000-01-01 | 2021-03-31 |
| John | Phone | 2021-04-01 | 2099-12-31 |

But now what I'm trying to do is the know the items that were owned by an owner for a given period.

**Here is an example :**

For the first table, the owner `Louis` I wanna know the items owned by him from the `2021-01-01` to the `2021-12-31`.

I can simply do this :

```
where date_from >= '2021-01-01' and date_to <= '2021-12-31'
```

But here is the problem... It will only give me the second row (the hat owned by Louis) since the software use default date format for current and first item. But in that case, Louis has 3 items owned during the year 2021.

So my question is :

How can I deal with my 2 default values ? Since those values are always the same. I wanna do something like : if the `date_from` value is between my where condition or equal to `2000-01-01` and `Date_to` is between the condition or equal to `2099-12-31` then display the item.

Comment: What is the expected output for Louis between `2021-03-15` and `2021-05-15`?

Comment: @SalmanA All the values. Since the ring is owned after `2021-03-15` and the jeans was owned before `2021-05-15`

Comment: See Damien's answer.

Comment: @SalmanA I just noticed that my answer of your question is actually the solution of the problem lol ! It's actually what Damien did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're basically trying to test for periods of ownership that overlap with the periods of your query, but your current test doesn't do this. It's close though.

Two periods overlap if the first *starts* before the second *ends* and the second *starts* before the first *ends*<sup>1</sup>.

Which is as simple as:

```
where date_to >= '2021-01-01' and date_from <= '2021-12-31'
```

I.e. just swap which columns you're comparing to the start and end values of your period.

And no need to special case the default start and end marker dates unless those are fixed and you need to support queries for other centuries as well.

---

<sup>1</sup>Your current test was "does one period entirely contain another period". I've seen people tie themselves in knots trying to enumerate different types of overlaps and write unique tests for each case but it turns out that there's a simpler test that doesn't need to enumerate those cases, and that's what I show here. If you're confused, here is a three line explanation:

Two periods either overlap or they don't. Checking if they don't overlap is simple: if first *ends before* second or first *starts after* second then they don't overlap. To test if they overlap, just invert the condition.

The only slight complexity is picking the right values of `<` or `<=` when you've decided whether two periods that exactly abut one another should or should not be considered an overlap.

Comment: Oh ok ! I see what I did wrong. Indeed, instinctively we don't think of simply turning the problem around but we try to manage the special cases and go directly to the hard mode! This worked perfectly, thank you :)

Comment: "tie themselves in knots" indeed. Main one I've seen is using two `OR` conditions instead of `AND` like you did, which is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've already said the answer

"date_from value is between my where condition or equal to 2000-01-01 and Date_to is between the condition or equal to 2099-12-31"

```
 ...
 where (date_from >= '2021-01-01' or date_from = '2000-01-01')
   and (date_to <= '2021-12-31' or date_to = '2099-12-31')
```

This should help

Comment: No. it needs a date range overlap query.